# Simple card game in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to reactjs and I'm trying to essentially make a simple "card game" where two cards go against each other and the higher score wins/stays, and the lower score loses, then the next card comes up against the initial winner. I have made a component that can be changed, but need help implementing it. Any help is appreciated or an example of how I can implement this.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import data0 from "./NFTs/Team1/0.json";
import data1 from "./NFTs/Team1/1.json";
import data2 from "./NFTs/Team1/2.json";
import data3 from "./NFTs/Team1/3.json";
import data4 from "./NFTs/Team2/0.json";
import data5 from "./NFTs/Team2/1.json";
import data6 from "./NFTs/Team2/2.json";
import data7 from "./NFTs/Team2/3.json";

export default function App() {
  //enter teams
  var matchups = [
    [data0, data1, data2, data3], //users 1
    [data4, data5, data6, data7] //users 2
  ];

  class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="NFT">
          <img
            className={this.props.className}
            src={this.props.src}
            alt="NFT"
          />
          <h1 className="nftnum">{this.props.name}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


  const NavBar = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  `;
  const TeamName = styled.h1`
    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50%;
  `;
  const Logo = styled.img`
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 25%;
  `;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Logo src="logo.png" />
      <NavBar>
        <TeamName>Aids Sack</TeamName>
        <TeamName>Balls Tucked</TeamName>
      </NavBar>
      <div className="nftWrapper">
        <Welcome
          className="leftNFT"
          name={matchups[0][0].name}
          src={matchups[0][0].properties.files[0].uri}
        />
        <Welcome
          className="rightNFT"
          name={matchups[1][0].name}
          src={matchups[1][0].properties.files[0].uri}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a runnable example to show us what you've tried: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: It would be great if you can put it on online editor such as `codepen` or `codesandbox` and provide us a runnable link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/newgame-11-4-xopv2?file=/src/App.js This is the current version of what I have. There is no function yet because I'm not sure what approach I can use. This is my previous version (with no graphics) that more shows what I'm trying to do. This completely emulates a single round, then I need it to show the second round as well, and so on: https://codesandbox.io/s/game-with-loop-0qtyv